# Java synchronization weird stuff

Tags: java, synchronization

I am learning synchronization in java, and I found a simple example on the internet, but according to what I have learnt about synchronization, it should not work.

The code:

```
public class PizzaHouse {

boolean pizzaArived = false;

synchronized void eatPizza(){
    while (!pizzaArived){
        try{
            System.out.println("waiting");
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Eating pizza");
}


synchronized void deliverPizza(){
    pizzaArived = true;
    System.out.println("Pizza delivered");
    notifyAll();
}
```

}

The code in main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PizzaHouse pizzaHouse = new PizzaHouse();

    Thread threadDelivering = new Thread(() -> pizzaHouse.deliverPizza());
    Thread threadEating = new Thread(() -> pizzaHouse.eatPizza());

    threadEating.start();
    threadDelivering.start();
}
```

}

The problem is that according to what I have learnt, this should result in a deadlock. Hypothesis:

1. the threadEating claims the lock
2. threadEating starts waiting
3. threadDelivering tries to claim the lock, but is unable to

-> deadlock, because the threadEating will never be notified and will never release the lock

However, when i execute that code, it works. Any assumptions?

Comment: `wait` releases the lock

Comment: oh thank you so much I forgot to check documentation